# How to iterate & retrieve values from NSArray of NSArrays of NSDictionaries

Tags: ios, arrays, nsarray, nsdictionary

I'm stumpped on how iterate and get values for an Array of Arrays of NSDictionaries (different classes/entities).   Here's what I'm currently doing:

1) Constructing two separate arrays of NSDictionaries (different entities)
2) Combining both arrays with:

```
NSMutableArray *combinedArrayofDicts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: sizesArrayOfDicts, wishListArrayOfDicts , nil];
```

3) Then archive combinedArrayofDicts :

```
NSData *dataToSend = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:combinedArrayofDicts];
```

4) Transmit over GameKit

```
[self.session sendDataToAllPiers:dataToSend withDataMode: GKSendDataReliable error:nil];
```

5) How would I manage traversing thru this array on the receiving end?  I want to fetch values by for each class which is key'ed by classname:

Here's how it looks via NSLog (2 Sizes Dicts, and 1 Wishlist Dict)

```
Printing description of receivedArray:
<__NSArrayM 0xbc65eb0>(
<__NSArrayM 0xbc651f0>(
{
    classname = Sizes;
    displayOrder = 0;
    share = 1;
    sizeType = Neck;
    value = "13\" or 33 (cm)";
},
{
    classname = Sizes;
    displayOrder = 0;
    share = 1;
    sizeType = Sleeve;
    value = "34\" or 86 (cm)";
}
)
,
<__NSArrayM 0xbc65e80>(
{
    classname = Wishlist;
    detail = "";
    displayOrder = 0;
    imageString = "";
    latitude = "30.33216666666667";
    link = "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=loc:30.332,-81.41";
    longitude = "-81.40949999999999";
    name = bass;
    share = 1;
    store = "";
}
)
)
(lldb)
```

In my for loop I'm issuing this:

```
NSString *value = [dict objectForKey:@"classname"];
```

and get an exception:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM objectForKey:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xbc651f0'

Is this frowned upon as far as mixing object types in arrays of arrays?

**@Will guided me to the answer with the right construct..  Here's the final answer:**

```
NSArray *receivedArray;
if(receivedArray.count>0){

    NSArray *combinedArrayofDicts = [receivedArray objectAtIndex:0];

    if(combinedArrayofDicts.count>=2){

        NSArray *sizesArray = [receivedArray objectAtIndex:0]; // Reference original received array
        for(NSDictionary *sizeDict in sizesArray){
            NSLog(@"%@",sizeDict);
        }

        NSArray *wishListArray = [receivedArray objectAtIndex:1]; // Reference original received array
        for(NSDictionary *wishDict in wishListArray){
            NSLog(@"%@",wishDict);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your for loop code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for fetching the required dictionaries use the following code,
Assume receivedArray as the array receive from Game center

> ```
> NSArray *receivedArray;
> if(receivedArray.count>0){
>     NSArray *combinedArrayofDicts = [receivedArray objectAtIndex:0];
>     if(combinedArrayofDicts.count>=2){
>         NSArray *sizesArray = [combinedArrayofDicts objectAtIndex:0];
>         for(NSDictionary *sizeDict in sizesArray){
>             NSLog(@"%@",sizeDict);
>         }
>         NSArray *wishListArray = [combinedArrayofDicts objectAtIndex:1];
>         for(NSDictionary *wishDict in wishListArray){
>             NSLog(@"%@",wishDict);
>         }
>    }
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks Will, I'll check it out and provide Feedback :)

Comment: this was almost perfect, and definitely got me 75% there.  Perfect construct!  The need to reference the original receivedArray when setting up sizesArray and wishListArray was needed... I'll post back the answer up in my original question if I can..Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

*how iterate and get values for an Array of Arrays of NSDictionaries*

As you said you have array of array of dictionaries, your current code will not retrive value of class name.

Your return values are in `NSArray` not in `NSDictionary`

So you need to do something like,

```
NSString *value = [returnArray[0][0] objectForKey:@"classname"];
```

You can iterate and get values like,

```
for (int i = 0; i < [returnArray count]; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < [returnArray[i] count]; j++) {
        NSDictionary *dict = (NSDictionary*)returnArray[i][j];
        NSLog(@"%@ ...",[dict objectForKey:@"classname"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bhargavi, I'll check this out and provide feedback.  Happy Tuesday, Cheers! :)

Comment: Technically this is a right answer as well.. Can I have 2 green check marks?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try:

```
NSString *value = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict objectForKey:@"classname"]];
```

By the looks of your output, I don't think "Sizes" is a string.

Comment: Hmm.. I think the problem I had was I was accessing the wrong part of the construct at this point, and not sure if this will work out of the box, in the same place... Thanks for the feedback though :)